# How to change the DPI value for screenshots?

Tags: windows-7, windows, screenshot, dpi

If I take screenshots under Win7 (e.g. size 600x600 pixels) and paste it into various applications they will appear with a size of ca. 15.8x15.8 cm. Because, apparently, the Windows system or the applications assume a pixel density of 96 DPI.
In those applications I need an image size of 7.9x7.9 cm. So, of course, I could scale all images manually down by 50%. However, is there any possibility to directly copy the screenshot automatically in the desired size?
This means, can I set somewhere that the pixel density for screenshots should be 192 DPI?

Some other suggestions (here on SuperUser and others...)
Well, I can copy&paste the image to an image viewer and set (or change) the DPI to 192 and paste it to the application. However, this intermediate step and using an extra program is not very practical.
Also changing the DPI value of the whole Windows system back and forth everytime is not considered as a practicable solution.

Comment: If the target application supported adjusting DPI, then you wouldn't have a question. Because the target application does NOT support DPI adjustment, the only other option is to use an intermediate application that DOES adjust DPI to do so. So, the question then becomes: what is the most efficient way to adjust DPI, and that is broad and opinion based because what is most efficient for someone else may not be so for you, or the question is what program(s) can do this, which is a software recommendation request, and not on-topic here.

Comment: I am not asking for an extra program. I want to **avoid** any extra program

Comment: And I hope I have clarified how, given the process you have described, that is not a possibility. Please use the EDIT button to clarify your question, possibly listing the specific program you are trying to get the images from and into.

Comment: MS Word (and other Office products) allow you to adjust the default DPI of images in File > Options > Advanced > Image Size and Quality.

Comment: well, this seems to be the case for MSOffice2016 (https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/change-the-default-resolution-for-inserting-pictures-in-office-2016-f4aca5b4-6332-48c6-9488-bf5e0094a7d2). I haven't found this for MSOffice<=2013, there is something just for image **export**, but not for image **import**. In general, my hope was that changing screenshot DPI could be done somehow in Windows system or some graphic card settings.

Comment: You don't say what you're using to take the screenshot.  The solution may be to use a screenshot program that includes resizing capability.

Comment: All Office versions I've worked with have image resizing. However, these usually refer to the absolute size in inches, not pixels.

Comment: @fixer1234 well, it could be anything... Alt+PrintScreen, Right-Mouseclick & copy an image from a browser, output of a program, etc. All have in common that the image is temporarily stored in the clipboard. I assume (pls correct me if I am wrong) that the Clipboard does not contain any DPI information. When pasting into other applications (Word, PPT, Libreoffice, ...) they just assume a DPI of 96. The question is whether this DPI value can be changed without use of a third program. If I believe the above link, MSOffice2016 can do this, but apparently older versions can't.

Comment: @music2myear I am not talking about resizing images in the normal way. Of course, all office versions can do this. The question was whether a different value than 96 DPI can be set somewhere (either by Windows system or the application) when pasting an image from the clipboard into another application.

Comment: @theozh, that was sort of my point.  You're using various bare-bones screen capture tools that just stick it in the clipboard at the default DPI, and then you're stuck if what you paste into doesn't include a resizing provision.  The only option at that point is 3rd party software.  I'm saying to instead, use a different screen capture tool, one that includes a resizing option before it is saved to the clipboard (or modifies the image in the clipboard).  Then, what's in the clipboard is already the size you need, and the workflow doesn't require a third tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, based on the comments, it looks like it can't be done with just some settings in Windows or with older Versions of MSOffice or LibreOffice etc. Even with MSOffice2016, only a few predefined DPI values would be possible. Hence, a "separate" application seems to be necessary. Since the framework of my project will be in Python, Python does not really count as additional program. With a minor issue, the solution for my question seems to be: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51879113/how-to-get-screenshot-and-change-dpi-on-the-clipboard

Answer (score 1):

The applications that can actually deal with DPI settings should allow you to specify the DPI when it converts.

DPI is nothing more than a conversion from pixels to physical size.

You do not specify what image editor you are using, but I know Photoshop has this setting.

You usually set this at the document resize screen. You can choose to change the DPI setting but keep the resolution in pixels the same. You may have to calculate what the width and height will become in CM using the new DPI setting for it to scale properly, but it will keep all the pixels the same.

What I usually do is this: On the image resize screen, I first copy the width of the amount of pixels I already have, then I change the DPI setting. The width changes. I paste back the old value, and now the CM measures change. I hit OK. The image dimensions change, but the amount of pixels stay the same. And the DPI has also changed.

That said, do note that if you don't alter the DPI setting in anyway and not resize the image, the same scaling automatically happen when you print out the image.

Also note, that if you keep the amount of pixels the same, and you increase the DPI, the physical size becomes smaller. The image will be sharper when printed, but also smaller. If you decrease the DPI, the physical dimensions increase, but the image becomes pixellated.

If you want a bigger image with more DPI, you need more pixels.

Comment: the question was if it is possible to change the dpi **without** another additional applications, like Photoshop, GIMP, IrfanView or others... if one can change any settings at all then they must be in Windows or in the applications, e.g. like Word, PPT, etc.

Comment: If the applications you are pasting the pics into do not offer their own DPI adjustment then you'll have to use an additional application that DOES support DPI adjustment to do that. If your target application supported DPI adjustment then you wouldn't have a question.

Comment: @music2myear OK, if so, the question boils down to: do e.g. Word, PowerPoint, LibreOffice offer DPI adjustment, which I may have not found yet? And do the Windows system or clipboard manager or anything offer anything like that?

Comment: The windows system does not have any setting for this. It must be in word. Don't forget... DPI is just a conversion from pixels to physical size. All windows can do is strip away a DPI setting so word has to recreate it.